# Middle "mouse click" on Touchpad with XFCE 4 on Ubuntu 20.04 with Dell XPS 13" 9300

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, touchpad

I'm struggling to find the Setting in XFCE4 where I could enable "middle mouse click" on my touchpad to paste copied text. I tried `synclient TapButton3=3` but it did not have an observable effect for me.

Any directions?

Edit:

```
Outer window is 0x3e00001, inner window is 0x3e00002

PropertyNotify event, serial 8, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x27 (WM_NAME), time 7308912, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 9, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x22 (WM_COMMAND), time 7308912, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 10, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x28 (WM_NORMAL_HINTS), time 7308912, state PropertyNewValue

CreateNotify event, serial 11, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    parent 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00002, (10,10), width 50, height 50
border_width 4, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 14, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x183 (WM_PROTOCOLS), time 7308912, state PropertyNewValue

MapNotify event, serial 15, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    event 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00002, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x191 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 7308913, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x18b (_NET_WM_DESKTOP), time 7308913, state PropertyNewValue

ConfigureNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    event 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00001, (0,0), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x380086e, override NO

ReparentNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    event 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00001, parent 0xc194ad,
    (12,58), override NO

ConfigureNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    event 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00001, (12,58), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0xc194bc, override NO

ConfigureNotify event, serial 20, synthetic YES, window 0x3e00001,
    event 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00001, (871,485), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x0, override NO

MapNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    event 0x3e00001, window 0x3e00001, override NO

VisibilityNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    state VisibilityUnobscured

Expose event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    (0,0), width 178, height 10, count 3

Expose event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    (0,10), width 10, height 58, count 2

Expose event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    (68,10), width 110, height 58, count 1

Expose event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    (0,68), width 178, height 110, count 0

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x1b5 (WM_STATE), time 7308918, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x1e6 (_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS), time 7308918, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x191 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 7308918, state PropertyNewValue

FocusIn event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x188 (_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS), time 7308919, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x191 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 7308919, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x191 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 7308919, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    atom 0x1ea (_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY), time 7308931, state PropertyNewValue

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7308983, (-56,252), root:(815,737),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7309951, (-56,252), root:(815,737),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310014, (-56,252), root:(815,737),
    state 0x4, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310155, (-56,238), root:(815,723),
    state 0x4, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310308, (-4,176), root:(867,661),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310374, (0,150), root:(871,635),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967185 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310375, (0,150), root:(871,635),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310382, (1,143), root:(872,628),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310389, (2,136), root:(873,621),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310396, (4,130), root:(875,615),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310403, (6,123), root:(877,608),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310410, (8,115), root:(879,600),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310417, (12,106), root:(883,591),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310424, (20,94), root:(891,579),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310432, (30,80), root:(901,565),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310439, (40,70), root:(911,555),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310446, (53,59), root:(924,544),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x3e00002, time 7310446, (53,59), root:(924,544),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310453, (78,45), root:(949,530),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967248 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310453, (78,45), root:(949,530),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310460, (101,31), root:(972,516),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310467, (122,19), root:(993,504),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310474, (133,12), root:(1004,497),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310481, (141,8), root:(1012,493),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310488, (147,5), root:(1018,490),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310496, (150,2), root:(1021,487),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310503, (152,1), root:(1023,486),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x7d0, subw 0x0, time 7310510, (155,-1), root:(1026,484),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

ClientMessage event, serial 37, synthetic YES, window 0x3e00001,
    message_type 0x183 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x181 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

Comment: Please run `xev` in the terminal and post the output.

Comment: @telometto done!

Comment: Did you try a triple-fingers tap? That's usually how it's handled.

Comment: Yeah @A.B I did try this.

Comment: Strange, let me try it again. :)

Comment: Sorry for earlier but I had to spend some time with my family. I see that the others have helped you out, though.

Comment: @telometto no worries! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `synclient TapButton3=3` but it will be lost after reboot (of course?).

Comment: Try adding `synclient TapButton3=3` to your `~/.profile` file. It should then be set each time your login shell runs, which happens when your machine boots up.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add this. @DavidYockey can I also query the current value of TapButton3 with `synclient`?

Comment: According to the [synclient man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/synclient), you should be able to.

Comment: @DavidYockey awesome. I'll read more carefully the man.

Comment: I probably should have qualified my last comment a bit... `man synclient` notes an option to list current user settings, which you'd likely need to grep or something to get a particular setting, and it's not clear if it'll output the default settings or just settings set by the user. Not having a touchpad, I don't have `synclient` installed, so I'm not in a position to check for sure.